# XBee library for Raspberry Pi

Tags: usb, wireless, serial, xbee

Is there any existing easy way to install a library for [XBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee) in Raspberry Pi?

I found [a library](http://dsnet.tu-plovdiv.bg/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Driver%20Module%20for%20XBee%20Device), but I don't yet posess the knowledge to get that library to work on the Raspberry Pi.

I have the XBee hooked up to my USB port and want to write a simple test program, one that just catches an [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character, like in *[Documentation: XBee for Raspberry Pi Tutorial](http://www.cooking-hacks.com/index.php/documentation/tutorials/raspberry-pi-xbee#step1)*.

How do I make it work?

Comment: Your link to the library leads to a 404 Not Found. Also, what programming language are you using / planning to use?